# Как сделать таблицу такого вида?

Tags: html, css, table

Как верстать таблицу такого вида? А именно как поделить ячейку на еще три ячейки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
th {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        asdf
      </th>
      <th>
        asd
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первой ячейке добавьте rowspan="3":

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        asdf
      </td>
      <td>
        asd
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        asd
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        asd
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```